# Error Building Cordova project VS2015 TS2503 TypeScript Cannot find namespace ''Core"

Tags: cordova

I've been attempting to build my cordova project for andorid and it builds with the error: TS2503 TypeScript Cannot find namespace ''Core". in  app.ts
The source of the error:

```
module SpeedSail {
"use strict";

angular.module("SpeedSail", ["SpeedSail.Core"])
    .run(['$cordova', function ($cordova: Core.Services.ICordovaService) {

    $cordova
        .ready(function () {
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.

    })
        .onPause(function () {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.

    })
        .onResume(function () {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.

    })
        .on('online', function () {
        // TODO: The application is currently online. Set the application behavior here.
        // Don't forget to add the org.apache.cordova.network-information plugin in order to have this event working.

    })
        .on('offline', function () {
        // TODO: The application is currently offline. Set the application behavior here.
        // Don't forget to add the org.apache.cordova.network-information plugin in order to have this event working.

    })
        .on('batterycritical', function () {
        // TODO: The device is entering the battery critical status. Set the application behavior here.
        // Don't forget to add the org.apache.cordova.battery-status plugin in order to have this event working.

    });
}]);
```

}
Source of Error being

```
Core.Services.ICordovaService
```

I can't figure out this issue I've not changed this code at all. Any Ideas?